# how to fill in table on template file from phpword?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, phpword

[image: source/template]

How to insert table from database employee to my template document as above?
I successfully filled company field.

code like bellow

```
require_once APPPATH.'libraries/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
public function cetaksurat()
{
   $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('source.docx');
   $templateProcessor->setValues([
        'company' => 'my company',
        //how to insert employee table from my database array result?
        //.....
   ]);
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result.docx");
   $templateProcessor->saveAs('php://output');
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case I would use:

$news2 = $this->phpword_model->get_employe(); //

```
        foreach($news2 as $key=>$values) {
    $array_values1 = $values['id'];
    $array_values2 = $values['name'];  
}

$templateProcessor->setValue('id', $array_values1);
$templateProcessor->setValue('name', $array_values2);


    $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
```

/// the first example is for a single record.
now this example is for multiple records.

```
        $news7 = $this->phpword_model->get_employes();
        $templateProcessor->cloneRow('id', count($news7));

         $i=1;
foreach($news7 as $key=>$values) {
    $templateProcessor->setValue('id#'.$i++, $values['id']); 
}

             $i2=1;
foreach($news7 as $key=>$values) {
    $templateProcessor->setValue('name#'.$i2++, $values['name']);
}

    $templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
```